# Get specific numbers from string

Tags: c#, string, split

In my current project I have to work alot with substring and I'm wondering if there is an easier way to get out numbers from a string.

Example:
I have a string like this:
12 text text 7 text

I want to be available to get out first number set or second number set.
So if I ask for number set 1 I will get 12 in return and if I ask for number set 2 I will get 7 in return.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will create an array of integers from the string:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        string text = "12 text text 7 text";
        int[] numbers = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(text, @"\d+") select int.Parse(m.Value)).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed! :D
Btw sorry for the down vote, didn't know I could not vote becouse I'm newly registered.

Comment: @TobiasLindberg: glad it helped, in that case you can undo the down vote meybe :) ?

Comment: Sorry it was just a client side thing, It didn't actually down vote you. Thanks again!

Comment: Then I'd be curious to know why someone downvoted the answer. You're welcome, in any case :)

Comment: @Jack really? Are you getting some error or it just doesn't do what expected?

Comment: PaoloTedesco: It was me then i think. So confusing because It first said that I was to new to give an upvote and it changed to a down vote. Anyway you got a up vote now :D

Comment: I get an error: I have added `System.Core.dll`, but I get `An implementation of `Cast' query expression pattern could not be found. Are you missing `System.Linq' using directive or `System.Core.dll' assembly reference? (CS1935) (atest)`

Comment: @Jack: have you tried what the error message suggests, i.e. adding a reference to System.Core.dll (I suppose `using System.Linq` is there, if you copied the example)

Comment: @PaoloTedesco: Thanks. Sorry for able not to add +1 again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good match for [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).

The basic regular expression would be `\d+` to match on (one or more digits).

You would iterate through the `Matches` collection returned from `Regex.Matches` and parse each returned match in turn.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, "\d+");

foreach(var match in matches)
{
    myIntList.Add(int.Parse(match.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using regular expressions, you can match `[0-9]+` which will match any run of numerals within your string. The C# code to use this regex is roughly as follows:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, "[0-9]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Here we check the Match instance.
if (match.Success)
{
    // here you get the first match
    string value = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

You will of course still have to parse the returned strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+$");
```

Comment: You are assuming leading `0`s are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

you can split the string in parts using string.Split, and then travese the list with a foreach applying int.TryParse, something like this:

```
string test = "12 text text 7 text";
var numbers = new List<int>();
int i;
foreach (string s in test.Split(' '))
{
     if (int.TryParse(s, out i)) numbers.Add(i);
}
```

Now numbers has the list of valid values

Comment: hi Oded, thanks for the catch. As mentioned in the first sentence, it should be TryParse. I have corrected it.